Zeppelin Spark interpreter NoSuchMethodError
When I execute zeppelin notebook with pyspark interpreter I get following InterpreterException:
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Settings.usejavacp()Lscala/tools/nsc/settings/MutableSettings$BooleanSetting;
Zeppelin Version:0.11.0
Spark Version:3.3.1 
Scala Version:2.12.15 
I will be thankful if anyone can help in this case.
